# Prove the following sequence is Cauchy

Tags: calculus, cauchy-sequences

I was proving the following sequence converges using Cauchy’s theorem as required:
$$
x_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-2\sqrt{n}.
$$
I can actually prove that it converges through proving it decreases and is bounded, but the question requires to prove it by Cauchy and I did not figure it out. Can anybody give me a hand?

———

I did the following job: in order to find a proper $N\in\mathbb{N}_+$ for a fixed $\epsilon>0$, calculate (supposing $m>n$)
\begin{align*}
|x_m-x_n|={}&\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}-2\sqrt{m}+2\sqrt{n}\right|\\
\leq{}&\left|\frac{m-n}{\sqrt{n}}-2\frac{m-n}{\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}}\right|,
\end{align*}
and I got stuck… I can’t let $m$ disappear and think only about $n$, which means I’m not able to find the $N$ as required.. Did I go too far on zooming the inequality?

———

So I followed the hint by @Gribouillis and get:
\begin{align*}
x_n-x_{n+1}={}&-2\sqrt{n}+2\sqrt{n+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\\
={}&\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}
\end{align*}
Which leads to
\begin{align*}
0\le x_n-x_{n+1}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}},
\end{align*}
And this immediately leads to
$$
|x_m-x_n|\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},\qquad (\text{supposing}\ m>n)
$$
So I can simply let $N=\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\right]+1$, thus $|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$. Thanks again to everyone commented below.

Comment: If it converges, then it's Cauchy...

Comment: You could try looking at $x_n-x_m$ and then try to bound this as a function of $m$ and $n$

Comment: You need $N = 1 + \lfloor\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\rfloor$. Also there are missing square roots in the equations.

Answer (score 1):

Noting that
\begin{eqnarray}
x_n&=&1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-2\sqrt{n}\\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{k-1}^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}dx-\int_1^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx+2\\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{k-1}^k(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})dx+2
\end{eqnarray}
one has, for $p>0$,
\begin{eqnarray}
|x_{n+p}-x_n|&=&\bigg|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\int_{k-1}^k(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})dx\bigg|\\
&\le&\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\int_{k-1}^k(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}})dx\\
&=&\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}})\\
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt n}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+p}}\\
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt n}.
\end{eqnarray}
So for $\epsilon>0$, letting $N=\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\right]+1$, one has
$$|x_{n+p}-x_n|<\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove that
\begin{equation}
0 \le x_n - x_{n+1}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}
\end{equation}